# Fade Upon A New Link

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get new page to load every time a user visits A new link, I have archived this but, Now what I want is to is when they visit A new link I want it to fade the new content in without refreshing the page obiviously.

How can I use the fade in effect?

Thanks

Heres the index.html (all other pages are the same with different content)

```
<html>
    <title>Title Here</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js">

    </script>
    <script src="js/func.js">

    </script>

    <head>  <a href="about.html" class="link"> Go To About</a>
            <a href="contact.html" class="link"> Go To Conact</a> 
    </head>
    <div class="content">

        <body>test</div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Heres the JQuery Code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".content").css("display", "none");
    $(".content").fadeIn(600);

    $("a").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var page = $(this).attr('href')
        $(".content").fadeIn(600);
        $('.content').load(page);
    });
});
```

Thanks,

Spudster

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this:

```
    $(".content").hide().load(page, function() {
        $(this).fadeIn(600);
    });
```

The [`.load()` function](http://api.jquery.com/load/) lets you specify a callback function that will be executed after the load is complete, so you can do the fade in there.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zw5xt/

Comment: I try it.let you know in a few secounds